# Blur behind UIImage not going away after image is dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, swift3

I've been trying to add a blur effect behind an image after I tap on it, however, it is not going away after I dismiss the image. The blur doesn't disappear.

```
func didTapImageView(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame

    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let newImageView = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    newImageView.frame = self.view.frame
    newImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true

    //newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)
    newImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    newImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    //blurEffectView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
    self.view.addSubview(newImageView)
}

func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

[image: Image with blur in backgroud]

How can I remove the blur after the tap? and also, how do I make it full screen? it doesn't seem to be working that either.

Comment: what mean of `how do I make it full screen`?

Comment: @aircraft yes, like the image right now shows behind the tab bar. I want it to show full screen like on the twitter app when you tap on a photo.

Comment: @BrunoRecillias - When you say `.scaleAspectFit` for an image's `contentMode` - unless the dimensions of the image are equal in scale to your device's screen dimensions, probably won't be full screen. You probably want to say something like `UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill` or `UIViewContentMode.scaleToFill`

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like when you call `dismissFullScreenImage` you are only removing the `UIImageView` from the superview. The `blurEffectView` is a separate subview entirely. You'll have to set a property for the effect view and then remove it when you call for the image to be removed. At the top of your class say something like like:

```
var blurEffectView:UIVisualEffectView!
```

Then in your `didTapImageView`:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame
```

Then when you call `dismissFullScreenImage`, you need to say something like :

```
func dismissFullscreenImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    blurEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I don't know what you mean "how do I make it fullscreen?" .. The visual effect already is fullscreen. At least it looks that way on your screenshot.

Comment: by full screen I mean on top of everything. The way it is right now I can still scroll down on the table view, and I can see the navBar and tab bar

Comment: @BrunoRecillias - so you mean like you want it constantly pinned to the edges of the screen, even when you're scrolling?

Comment: like when you tap on an image on twitter or Facebook, it got full screen and you either tap/scroll down to dismiss the image. In my case I did a tap, but the image is not going full screen. I don't know if that makes sense

Comment: @BrunoRecillas - I think what you want to do is make an entire ViewController that just displays the image, and then when you tap on it, it dismisses and goes back to the main screen?

Comment: so there's no way of just putting the current blur on top of everything?

Comment: @BrunoRecillas - I don't think you can do that with a TabBarController. But hey it's really easy. Just create a new Swift file that's a `UIViewController`, and in `viewDidLoad` add all the code you have here under `didTapImageView`, and replace that method by instantiating the new VC and presenting it. `let showImageVC = ShowImageViewController()` and present it `present(showImageVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`. Then all yo have to do is in the new VC when you handle `dismissFullscreenImage` just say `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: do I have to send any sort of data? like sending the image data? or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133127/discussion-between-pierce-and-bruno-recillas).